# Is it possible to solve this reduced quintic equation?

Tags: polynomials, quintics

Since there is no general formula for quintic equations, is there for a formula for quintic equations of the type:
$$ax^5+bx^3+cx+d=0$$

or is it at least possible to solve:
$$16x^5-20x^3+5x-q=0$$

in terms of q?
I would really appreciate your help and if this can be solved for q, I'll be sure to come up with some very interesting posts and articles for all of you.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hmmm, I haven't put too much thought into this yet, but I highly doubt there'll be an explicit solution...

Comment: I tried factoring a little, but it didn't seem to work, **yet**.

Comment: For $|q| \le 1$, the second quintic has roots $\cos\left(\frac15\cos^{-1}q + \frac{2\pi k}{5}\right)$ for $k = 0,\ldots,4$.

Comment: very nice of you comming up with this, however that solution was the point of the equation and not really the solution i was hoping for.

Comment: This is the way to find the formula for the fifth of an angle. ( $sin(x/5)$ )

Comment: If you like radicals more than trigonometric functions, you can translate achille's solution directly to radicals: $x=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt[5]{q+\sqrt{q^2-1}}+\sqrt[5]{q-\sqrt{q^2-1}}\right)$